# Get value input form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I would like to retrieve the password value type for the display in the console.log .
I use a html form with ng-model="passwd" to retrieve the value.
And I then uses a controller with $scope.passwd=null; to retrieve the input field.
For now, $scope.passwd remains null in google chrome => Console

```
'use strict';

angular.module('djoro.controllers')

.controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform){

  $scope.passwd = null;

  $scope.startSmartconfig = function(passwd){       

        var onSuccess = function(success){

          $scope.passwd = passwd;
        };

        var onFail = function(){};

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){

        $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.startSmartconfig(onSuccess, onFail, $scope.passwd);
            console.log('Password  = ' + $scope.passwd);
        });

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="wifi_form" class="simple-form">            
    <div class="list input-fields">
       <label class="item item-input" show-hide-container>
         <span class="input-label">Password : </span>
           <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="passwd" id="passwd" show-hide-input>
       </label>         
   </div>  
</form>
<div class="startWifi">
      <button class="button button-full button-balanced" ng-click="startSmartconfig()">Start</button>
 
</div>
```

Someone an idea to edit the entered value ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$scope.passwd = null;` to `$scope.passwd = '';`

You are using `ng-click="startSmartconfig()"` and passing nothing but in controller, you have used `$scope.startSmartconfig = function(passwd){` so this code will not work.

Set controller function to `$scope.startSmartconfig = function(){` and another thing is angularjs is **two way binding** means when you add value in input text with ng-model="passwd", it also bind the textbox value to $scope.passwd.

Comment: chrome://inspect , console.log "password = nothing" by using $scope.passwd = ' ';

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of `$window.cordova` thing but what I observed is you didn't pass `passwd` in `ng-click="startSmartconfig()"` in html and you are assigning the `passwd` to `$scope.passwd` which will be undefined.

And no need to pass `passwd` in function. You can directly get updated value in `$scope.passwd`